# Why does Sprite Kit cause a collision here?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have a file, `Categories.h`, which defines the category bitmasks for my SpriteKit Game. Inside it is this:

```
#ifndef BallRoll_Categories_h
#define BallRoll_Categories_h

static u_int8_t ballCategory = 2;
static u_int8_t collideCategory = 6;
static u_int8_t contactCategory = 4;

#endif
```

I also have a class named `BRPowerup` which has this method in its implementation:

```
-(id)initWithType:(int)type
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        self.powerupType = type;
        self.size = CGSizeMake(32, 32);
        self.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:sprites[self.powerupType]];
        self.name = @"powerup";
        self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:self.size.width / 2];
        self.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
        self.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
        self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = contactCategory;
        self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
        self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = ballCategory;
        NSLog(@"init");
    }
    return self;
}
```

Inside `BRMyScene.h`, this code is ran in the `initWithSize:` method.

```
self.ball = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ball.png"];
        self.ball.position = CGPointMake(100, 100);
        self.ball.size = CGSizeMake(32, 32);
        self.ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:self.ball.size.width / 2];
        self.ball.physicsBody.density = .7;
        self.ball.physicsBody.restitution = .25;
        self.ball.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ballCategory;
self.ball.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = contactCategory;
        self.ball.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = collideCategory;
        self.ball.name = @"ball";
        [self addChild:self.ball];
```

Contacts are detected perfectly, but the ball still collides with things outside of `collideCategory` and bounces off the powerups. It also collides with other things outside of collideCategory.

Please leave a comment if more code is needed.

Help would be appreciated! Thank you in advance for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared your category masks as follows-

```
static u_int8_t ballCategory = 2;    // 00000010
static u_int8_t collideCategory = 6; // 00000110
static u_int8_t contactCategory = 4; // 00000100
```

It appears that the **collideCategory** equals **ballCategory | contactCategory**

The line `self.ball.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = collideCategory;` is therefor setting the ball to collide with other physics bodies of **ballCategory** *or* **contactCategory**.

Make **collideCategory** it's own category by giving it its own unique bit like 00001000 which is equal to 8. Try `collideCategory = 8` instead of 6.

One last note is that the bit mask I believe should be a 32bit (*uint32_t*) mask not 8bit (*u_int8_t*) as per your declarations. Try this -

```
static const uint32_t ballCategory = 0x1 << 1;    // 00000010 (last 8 bits of 32bit mask)
static const uint32_t contactCategory = 0x1 << 2; // 00000100
static const uint32_t collideCategory = 0x1 << 3; // 00001000
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! I do have one question, however. I'm not a genius with bitmasks like this but I do understand binary and other mathematical bases. I believe that the comments on your 32-bit numbers are in 8-bit because the 32-bit numbers are small enough to be 8-bit numbers, and after some searching, I've found why the collision between the categories occurs. My question is: can a collision of this sort happen with the 32-bit numbers as well? Also, why do the 32-bit number double each time rather than go up by one? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @joeelectricity There are only 32 possible categories, 1 for each bit. From Apple's documentation: "Whenever a potential interaction occurs, the category mask of each body is tested against the contact and collision masks of the other body. Sprite Kit performs these tests by logically ANDing the two masks together. If the result is a nonzero number, then that interaction occurs." The number '6' in binary is 00000110 so when you AND that with '2' or '4' you're going to get a non-zero number and the interaction will occur.